# Finding the inverse of a function involving logarithms

Tags: calculus, functions, asymptotics, approximation-theory

Let $A \asymp B$ mean that there exists universal constants $m,M >0$ such that $mA \leq B \leq MA$. Let $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\log n \leq k \leq n$. I want to prove that

$$
k \log(\frac{n}{k}+1)=m \Rightarrow k \asymp \frac{m}{\log(\frac{n}{m}+1)}.
$$
Can anyone give me useful directions about where to start with? I am finding it difficult to express $k$ as a function of $m$ explicitly.

Comment: the $m$ in the equation is also the universal constant $m$?

Comment: @AdamFrancey: No, it's a variable obviously. It depends on $k,n$.